# Bootstrap text aligning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

My text in the website is like this:

```
Username: text
money: text
level: 5
rank: new
```

I want to change it ot be like that:

```
Username:    text
money:       text
level:       5
rank:        new
```

with bootstrap.

How I can do it?

My code is:

```
<div class="caption">
money: <span class="label label-default">1354</span><br/>
bank money: <span class="label label-default">2314 <i class="fa fa-money"></i></span><br/>
gold: <span class="label label-warning">15</span><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide your current code.

Comment: This is one place...I'd use a table.

Comment: @George I added the code to my question. Paulie_D, I know how to use table but im not sure of it will be optimized to my bootstrap. I want it to be responsive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap documentation is really clear. Use the `col-*-*` classes to do what you needs. The grid system is the base principle of bootstrap.

The forms examples (horizontal) give you what you need: [RTFM here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-horizontal)

To simplify :

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">Username</div><div class="col-sm-10">text</div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">money</div><div class="col-sm-10">text</div>
</div>
```